# Select Numbers Before and After String Values - Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to create 2 new columns from a single column.

My data looks like this:

```
userid:5438888,locationid:84646646478,property:g
```

I want to make a new column for the `userid`, and a new column for the `locationid`. There are many more rows, and the `userid`s and `locationid`s aren't always going to be the same length throughout the dataset.

I am assuming there is a way to split the text after `:` and before `,` but I am not sure how it would work doing this twice inside the string. I don't care about the property part of the string. Solely `userid` and `locationid`.

Comment: This seems related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046879/splitting-a-text-string-to-matching-columns-in-presto

Comment: I tried that forum with the following code, but wasnt getting any values                                                                       
               with t as (
  SELECT split_to_map(attribution_site_id, ',',':') map from table)
  
  select element_at(map, 'userid') as u1,
  element_at(map, 'locationid') as u2
  from t

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with with the [`split_to_map()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#split_to_map) function:

```sql
WITH data(attribution_site_id) AS (
    VALUES 'userid:5438888,locationid:84646646478,property:g'
),
t AS (
    SELECT split_to_map(attribution_site_id, ',',':') map
    FROM data
)
SELECT element_at(map, 'userid') as userid,
       element_at(map, 'locationid') as locationid
FROM t
```

which produces:

```
 userid  | locationid
---------+-------------
 5438888 | 84646646478
```